# Brook's theorem. Where I make a mistake?

Tags: graph-theory

please explain me one thing:
According to Brook's theorem $ \chi(G )  \le \deg(u) $
But it can't be true. After all, there are $\deg(u) + 1 $ colors and I'm enclosing a draw.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmw6K.png

$\deg(u) = 5 $ and there are six colors, and graph isn't complet and it not odd-cycle. I don't understand.

What mistake I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chromatic number of a graph isn't defined from any colouring you want, but from the *optimal* colouring. Your graph can be coloured using only two colours (one for vertex $u$ and one for all the rest). Therefore $\chi(G) = 2$, and the theorem still holds.